# C#/LINQ/Objects/Lists: How to populate a TreeView the good way?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, treeview

I'm trying to display a bunch of information in a TreeView. For Example:

```
Continent 1
    Country 1
        City 1
        City 2
        City 3
    Country 2
        City 1
        City 2
    Country 3
Continent 2
    Country 1
        City 1
        City 2
Continent 3
```

This information is stored in classes/objects via lists. So an object/class of type Continent includes a list with several objects/classes of type Country (of course also some methods, properties etc.). All data was populated via LINQ out of an XML file.

Now, I could take the list with all continents inside - and foreach it. Inside this foreach, I foreach the list with all countries. And then I foreach...
The easy way, but this results in really nasty code, I think (my nodes go way deeper than 3 levels...)

So is there an easy way to accomplish this? Maybe with LINQ? e.g.

```
TreeView.Nodes =
    List[Countries].All.Where(Country.Name = Node.Text).Add(
        (List[Cities].All.Where(City.Name = Node.Text).Add(
            List[People].All.Where(Person.Name = Note.Text)));
```

I know, just rubbish code, but this way it would look way more beautiful than with all those nested foreachs.

I hope you can help.

Comment: How about a recursive data structure to store your info and a recursive method to setup the tree?

Comment: @GavinSinai How do you mean 'recursive'? I don't think it's possible to 'glob' an object if there are any lists inside like scanning a directory for further directories/levels. Maybe an example, please?

Answer (score 1):

In XAML you can use the [HierarhicaDataTemplate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx)

Comment: Wow. That one looks interesting. But I don't see how I can apply this to my existing data without looping through each level (object) by myself (which would lead to the basic method using foreach). Maybe an example?

Comment: The example is in the article. In the hierarhical template you set the ItemSource to the next level (thus hierahical), which can be of the same type if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try recursion.

First define a recursive data structure to store your node information.

```
public interface IRecursiveStructure
{
   string Name {get;}
   IList<IRecursiveStructure> Children {get;}
}
```

Implement the interface and populate accordingly.

Then to load the tree node, use a recursive method (this is untested pseudocode).

```
public void LoadTreeNodes(IRecursiveStructure data, TreeNode parentNode)
{
   foreach(var child in data.Children)
   {
        node = new Node{Name=data.Name};
        parentNode.Add(node).
        LoadTreeNodes(node,child);
   }

}
```

This is only a pseudocode example, so you will need to work on it a bit to get it working.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion for more about the concept of recursion.

Comment: Here I see the problem in the variety of my objects.
Some of them have 2 lists inside, some of them don't have a string that indicates the "Name" (sometimes an integer, another time I have to load the name from a file first for certain circumstances etc.)
An interface implies that the object have to follow a certain structure which is not given at any time..

Comment: You need to implement the interface per class. Each class will have a different implementation. Not sure how else you can solve this problem "elegantly".

Comment: Okay. Got this. It's more elegant than just foreaching.. What about the case when an object has 2 lists? In the foreach above, it just loops through the list Children, implying there's just 1 list per object.